# Apache2 installation problem in ubuntu 14.04 Lts

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, apache2

I'm Novice to use Ubuntu. I recently install 14.04 in my system. I had installed lamp and then I forgot MySQL password. So I had permanently remove lamp. Now I'm trying to install it again but it's not working:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

then i tried

```
sudo service apache2 restart
/etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
/etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Why is this happening?  What can I do to remedy the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First it sound like some things didnt get removed like they should have.
Press Ctrl + Alt + T to open a Terminal.  At which point you will type in the following

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

This removes all files with this package including the config files.  At which point you can reinstall the files.

Comment: it gives **warning: while removing apache2, directory '/var/www/html' not empty so not removed**